# Subclassing ndarray, "all"

Tags: python, numpy

I defined a class that is a subclass of `ndarray`. Now, I'm having a problem with `numpy.all`. For example, if I apply this method it on a normal `ndarray` of Bool, I only get one boolean value, as expected. On the contrary, if I apply `all` to an instance of my subclass, I get a 0-d instance `ndarray` containing the expected boolean value, but numpy wont let me index it to extract the single value:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed
```

Now, the question is: How do I modify the `all` method to work as expected on my subclass? 
If this is not possible, how can I extract the single value from this 0-d ndarray?

Comment: Would need to see your class definition (minimal subset of code that reproduces the problem). Are you aware that ndarray subclassing is usually done by overshadowing `__new__` and `__array_finalize__` rather than `__init__`?

Comment: To extract the value from a 0-d array `x`, you could just say `bool(x)`. Or (maybe) use it as if it were a scalar without bothering to convert. Or use the output of `x.flatten()` which will turn anything 1-d.

Comment: In my implementation, `np.all(x)` just calls `arr.all()`, where `arr` is the output of `array(x, copy=False)` - probably `x` itself. Is your `all()` method doing anything non-standard?

Comment: Your `__array_wrap__` can decide to return a scalar. Also you can index 0-d arrays easily with `arr[()]` to get a scalar.

Comment: How are you constructing the array with the new class?  How does this array display?  It's basic values like `shape` and `dtype`?